# topological group operation vs homotopy group operation

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

Let $X$ be a topological group. Let $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ representing elements of $\pi_n(X)$. Is it true that

$$ [\tau_1] [\tau_2] = [\tau_1 \tau_2] $$
in $\pi_n(X)$?,

where of course "$[\tau_1] [\tau_2]$" refers to the $\pi_n(X)$ group operation, and by $\tau_1 \tau_2$ I mean the map $S^n \ni x \mapsto \tau_1(x) \tau_2(x)$.

I know from greenberg harper algebraic topology a first course, page 30, that this is true for n=1.

It seems to me that the answer is a simple "yes", but I wonder why I can't find it on the internet.

Comment: does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eckmann-Hilton_argument#The_Eckmann.E2.80.93Hilton_result

provide an answer to the question?

Comment: I don't see how to use E-H here since you don't have two operations on one set but here each operation is on a different set. Anyway, interesting question and I'm curious about the answer in either direction. Can we say anything concrete e.g. about $SU(2)$?

Comment: I don't understand your objection: we do have two group operations on the same set $\pi_n(X)$: the first one is the standard one, the second one is the pointwise product.

Comment: Ah, I see, I misunderstood your construction. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [Eckmann-Hilton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eckmann-Hilton_argument#The_Eckmann.E2.80.93Hilton_result) applies. Interestingly, this implies that all of the homotopy groups of a topological group are *abelian*. For higher homotopy groups, this is not so interesting, because they are always abelian, regardless of the space. For $n=1$, however, it is not content-less: it tells us that the fundamental group of a topological group is abelian. Fundamental groups are not always abelian!

Thus, for instance, it is impossible to put a topological group structure on the twice-punctured plane.